# Oracle Identity Federation - RCU OID Schema Creation Failure

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, saml, federated-identity

I am trying to install OIF - Oracle Identity federation as per the OBE http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/oif/11g/r1/oif_install/oif_install.htm

1. I have installed the Oracle 11gR2 11.2.0.3 with the charset = AL32UTF8 and db_block size of 8K and nls_length_semantics=CHAR. Created database and listener needed.
2. Installed weblogic 10.3.6
3. Started installation of OIM - Oracle identity management, chosen install and configure option and schema creation options.
4. Installation goes fine, but during configuration it fails. Below is the relevant part of the logs.

I have tried multiple times just to fail again and again. If someone can kindly shed some light as what is going wrong in here. Please let me know, if you need more info on the setup...

```
_File : ...//oraInventory/logs/install2013-05-30_01-18-31AM.out_
ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded

Percent Complete: 62
Repository Creation Utility: Create - Completion Summary
Database details:
Host Name : vccg-rh1.earth.com
Port : 1521
Service Name : OIAMDB
Connected As : sys
Prefix for (non-prefixable) Schema Owners : DEFAULT_PREFIX
RCU Logfile : /data/OIAM/installed_apps/fmw/Oracle_IDM1_IDP33/rcu/log/rcu.log
RCU Checkpoint Object : /data/OIAM/installed_apps/fmw/Oracle_IDM1_IDP33/rcu/log/RCUCheckpointObj
Component schemas created:
Component Status Logfile
Oracle Internet Directory Failed /data/OIAM/installed_apps/fmw/Oracle_IDM1_IDP33/rcu/log/oid.log

Repository Creation Utility - Create : Operation Completed
Repository Creation Utility - Dropping and Cleanup of the failed components
Repository Dropping and Cleanup of the failed components in progress.
Percent Complete: 93
Percent Complete: -117
Percent Complete: 100
RCUUtil createOIDRepository status = 2------------------------------------------------- java.lang.Exception: RCU OID Schema Creation Failed
at oracle.as.idm.install.config.IdMDirectoryServicesManager.doExecute(IdMDirectoryServicesManager.java:792)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:375)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:88)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:105)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:96)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:186)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:81)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:86)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---

```
_File : ...///fmw/Oracle_IDM1_IDP33/rcu/log/oid.log_
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rp_dn on ct_dn (parentdn,rdn)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded

Edited by: 1008964 on May 30, 2013 12:10 PM

Edited by: 1008964 on May 30, 2013 12:12 PM
```

---

Update :

I looked at the logs again and tracked which sql statements were leading to the above error…

```
CREATE BIGFILE  TABLESPACE "OLTS_CT_STORE" EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT  AUTO  DATAFILE '/data/OIAM/installed_apps/db/oradata/OIAMDB/gcats1_oid.dbf' SIZE 32M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10240K MAXSIZE  UNLIMITED;


CREATE TABLE ct_dn (
        EntryID                 NUMBER NOT NULL,
        RDN                     varchar2(1024) NOT NULL,
        ParentDN                varchar2(1024)  NOT NULL)
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT
TABLESPACE OLTS_CT_STORE MONITORING;



*CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rp_dn on ct_dn (parentdn,rdn)
TABLESPACE OLTS_CT_STORE
PARALLEL COMPUTE STATISTICS;*
```

I ran these statements from sqlplus and I was able to create the index without issues and as per the table space creation statement, autoextend is on.  If RCU – repo creation utility runs to create the schemas needed, it fails with the same error as earlier.  Any pointers ?

Comment: What are the size of those columns? AL32UTF8 is a multibyte per char character set. Check here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1007156

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp: Not sure as they are executed by RCU internally. No luck as per the link/thread, i bounced the database..same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Setting NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE worked